# Apache Hadoop 2.6.0 Source compilation issue

Tags: maven, hadoop

I am compiling Hadoop 2.6.0 in 64 bitcentos 6.5 and  getting below error message. Anyone who can help me please?

**Environment Detail:**

- Jave Version: 1.7.0_71-b14
- Maven Version: Apache Maven 3.2.5
- Open SSL version: OpenSSL 1.0.x
- protoc Version: libprotoc 2.5.0
- Cmake Version:  2.8.12.2

Error message detail is below:

```
[INFO] Reactor Summary:
[INFO]
[INFO] Apache Hadoop Main ................................. SUCCESS [  2.259 s]
[INFO] Apache Hadoop Project POM .......................... SUCCESS [  1.570 s]
[INFO] Apache Hadoop Annotations .......................... SUCCESS [  1.853 s]
[INFO] Apache Hadoop Assemblies ........................... SUCCESS [  0.211 s]
[INFO] Apache Hadoop Project Dist POM ..................... SUCCESS [  1.731 s]
[INFO] Apache Hadoop Maven Plugins ........................ SUCCESS [  2.147 s]
[INFO] Apache Hadoop MiniKDC .............................. SUCCESS [ 43.369 s]
[INFO] Apache Hadoop Auth ................................. FAILURE [04:09 min]
[INFO] Apache Hadoop Auth Examples ........................ SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Hadoop Common ............................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Hadoop NFS .................................. SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Hadoop KMS .................................. SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Hadoop Common Project ....................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Hadoop HDFS ................................. SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Hadoop HttpFS ............................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Hadoop HDFS BookKeeper Journal .............. SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Hadoop HDFS-NFS ............................. SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Hadoop HDFS Project ......................... SKIPPED
[INFO] hadoop-yarn ........................................ SKIPPED
[INFO] hadoop-yarn-api .................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] hadoop-yarn-common ................................. SKIPPED
[INFO] hadoop-yarn-server ................................. SKIPPED
[INFO] hadoop-yarn-server-common .......................... SKIPPED
[INFO] hadoop-yarn-server-nodemanager ..................... SKIPPED
[INFO] hadoop-yarn-server-web-proxy ....................... SKIPPED
[INFO] hadoop-yarn-server-applicationhistoryservice ....... SKIPPED
[INFO] hadoop-yarn-server-resourcemanager ................. SKIPPED
[INFO] hadoop-yarn-server-tests ........................... SKIPPED
[INFO] hadoop-yarn-client ................................. SKIPPED
[INFO] hadoop-yarn-applications ........................... SKIPPED
[INFO] hadoop-yarn-applications-distributedshell .......... SKIPPED
[INFO] hadoop-yarn-applications-unmanaged-am-launcher ..... SKIPPED
[INFO] hadoop-yarn-site ................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] hadoop-yarn-registry ............................... SKIPPED
[INFO] hadoop-yarn-project ................................ SKIPPED
[INFO] hadoop-mapreduce-client ............................ SKIPPED
[INFO] hadoop-mapreduce-client-core ....................... SKIPPED
[INFO] hadoop-mapreduce-client-common ..................... SKIPPED
[INFO] hadoop-mapreduce-client-shuffle .................... SKIPPED
[INFO] hadoop-mapreduce-client-app ........................ SKIPPED
[INFO] hadoop-mapreduce-client-hs ......................... SKIPPED
[INFO] hadoop-mapreduce-client-jobclient .................. SKIPPED
[INFO] hadoop-mapreduce-client-hs-plugins ................. SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Hadoop MapReduce Examples ................... SKIPPED
[INFO] hadoop-mapreduce ................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Hadoop MapReduce Streaming .................. SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Hadoop Distributed Copy ..................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Hadoop Archives ............................. SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Hadoop Rumen ................................ SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Hadoop Gridmix .............................. SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Hadoop Data Join ............................ SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Hadoop Ant Tasks ............................ SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Hadoop Extras ............................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Hadoop Pipes ................................ SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Hadoop OpenStack support .................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Hadoop Amazon Web Services support .......... SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Hadoop Client ............................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Hadoop Mini-Cluster ......................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Hadoop Scheduler Load Simulator ............. SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Hadoop Tools Dist ........................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Hadoop Tools ................................ SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Hadoop Distribution ......................... SKIPPED
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 05:06 min
[INFO] Finished at: 2015-06-23T17:13:19+01:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 62M/150M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project hadoop-auth: Could not resolve dependencies for project org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-auth:jar:2.6.0: Failed to collect dependencies at org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-core:jar:7.0.55: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-core:jar:7.0.55: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-core:pom:7.0.55 from/to repository.jboss.org (http://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public/): Connect to repository.jboss.org:80 [repository.jboss.org/209.132.182.33] failed: Connection timed out -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/DependencyResolutionException
[ERROR]
[ERROR] After correcting the problems, you can resume the build with the command
[ERROR]   mvn <goals> -rf :hadoop-auth
```

Below is the Pom.xml of hadoop-auth (project)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--
 Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
 you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
 You may obtain a copy of the License at

   http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

 Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 limitations under the License. See accompanying LICENSE file.
-->
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0
                      http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <parent>
    <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
    <artifactId>hadoop-project</artifactId>
    <version>2.6.0</version>
    <relativePath>../../hadoop-project</relativePath>
  </parent>
  <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
  <artifactId>hadoop-auth</artifactId>
  <version>2.6.0</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <name>Apache Hadoop Auth</name>
  <description>Apache Hadoop Auth - Java HTTP SPNEGO</description>

  <properties>
    <maven.build.timestamp.format>yyyyMMdd</maven.build.timestamp.format>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <!-- Used, even though 'mvn dependency:analyze' doesn't find it -->
      <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
      <artifactId>hadoop-annotations</artifactId>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
      <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
      <artifactId>jetty-util</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
      <artifactId>jetty-util</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
      <artifactId>jetty</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
     <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
      <artifactId>tomcat-embed-core</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
      <artifactId>tomcat-embed-logging-juli</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
      <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>log4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
      <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
      <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
      <artifactId>hadoop-minikdc</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
      <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.directory.server</groupId>
      <artifactId>apacheds-kerberos-codec</artifactId>
      <scope>compile</scope>
        <exclusions>
          <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.apache.directory.api</groupId>
            <artifactId>api-asn1-ber</artifactId>
          </exclusion>
          <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.apache.directory.api</groupId>
            <artifactId>api-i18n</artifactId>
          </exclusion>
          <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.apache.directory.api</groupId>
            <artifactId>api-ldap-model</artifactId>
          </exclusion>
          <exclusion>
            <groupId>net.sf.ehcache</groupId>
            <artifactId>ehcache-core</artifactId>
          </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.zookeeper</groupId>
      <artifactId>zookeeper</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.curator</groupId>
      <artifactId>curator-framework</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.curator</groupId>
      <artifactId>curator-test</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <phase>prepare-package</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>jar</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
        <configuration>
          <attach>true</attach>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>prepare-jar</id>
            <phase>prepare-package</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>jar</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
          <execution>
            <id>prepare-test-jar</id>
            <phase>prepare-package</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>test-jar</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>findbugs-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
          <excludeFilterFile>${basedir}/dev-support/findbugsExcludeFile.xml</excludeFilterFile>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>

  <profiles>
    <profile>
      <id>docs</id>
      <activation>
        <activeByDefault>false</activeByDefault>
      </activation>
      <build>
        <plugins>
          <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
              <execution>
                <phase>package</phase>
                <goals>
                  <goal>site</goal>
                </goals>
              </execution>
            </executions>
          </plugin>
          <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
              <execution>
                <configuration>
                  <dependencyLocationsEnabled>false</dependencyLocationsEnabled>
                </configuration>
                <phase>package</phase>
                <goals>
                  <goal>dependencies</goal>
                </goals>
              </execution>
            </executions>
          </plugin>
          <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
              <execution>
                <phase>package</phase>
                <goals>
                  <goal>javadoc</goal>
                </goals>
              </execution>
            </executions>
          </plugin>
        </plugins>
      </build>
    </profile>
  </profiles>
</project>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IN your pom, you have the dependency for tomcat-embed-core.jar, which needs to be fetched from jboss.org repository, and unable to do so. Verify, if that is the actual repository. If it is, verify your proxy settings which allows your system to download those jars

Comment: I don't have any kind of restricted network/proxy at home.

Comment: Please see in eclipse if the referenced jar is added. That can be a good starting point.

Comment: Can you tell me how can I add and where I have to add it?

Comment: I mean to say, the dependencies which are present in pom.xml, will be shown in eclipse, under Maven Dependencies. So you can check there is the jar is added. If not, then try to do aven->clean and install again. As a last step, you can also delete the \.m2\repository folder(where you local maven repository is located), and perform the clean, install again to fetch all the jars again